# GNU LD giving errors when using C++ standard library

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, std, ld

I am writing an operating system in c++ and assembly and trying to use the standard library string.h but gnu ld is throwing this following error:

```
ld: lib/usercode/apps/textedit.o: in function `TextEdit::KeyStrike(char*)':
textedit.cpp:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
ld: textedit.cpp:(.text+0x2a1): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
ld: textedit.cpp:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
```

Have I messed up the linker or I have to do something else. The .ld file is as follows:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    _KernelStart = .;
    .text : ALIGN(0x1000)
    {
        *(.text)
    }
    .data : ALIGN(0x1000)
    {
        *(.data)
    }
    .rodata : ALIGN(0x1000)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }
    .bss : ALIGN(0x1000)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }
    _KernelEnd = .;
}
```

The c++ file is this:

```
#include "textedit.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string prntText = "hello";

void TextEdit::KeyStrike(char* Char){
    string str = "hello world";
    text = &Textbox(this, buffer, font, Point{0,0}, SizeW{this->bounds.boundSize.Width,this->bounds.boundSize.Height}, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF000000, str /*Parse for printing*/, false, "");
}
```

For compiling c++ code I use gcc and assembly - nasm. I don't know how to fix it and had it for a week. All help will be nice.

Comment: How do you invoke the ld command? Are you sure you are giving it a path to static libstdc++?

Comment: What command did you use to link?  You might need to link libstdc++, and/or G++ put code in some sub-sections like `.text.something` for link-time duplicate removal or `.text.cold` or whatever, and your linker script isn't reading those sections of your input objects.

Comment: I'm guessing you're compiling with `gcc` instead of `g++`

Comment: I see `.KernelStart` and `.KernelEnd` in that linker script of yours... are you aware that you can't just go ahead and use the standard library in your kernel code? `std::string`, for example, will assume that dynamic memory allocation is provided for (among *many* other things)....

Comment: I switched to g++ and its still giving the same errors.

Comment: You are trying to link to a **user-space** C++ standard library from code apparently intended to be compiled to **kernel-space**. That **will** not work, even if we figure out the correct `ld` parameters.